# New fonts in SSRS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2008

I am trying to add a new font to my computer to have it used in SSRS. When I install the new font, it does not appear in the list of fonts available to be used within SSRS. I've even installed a new service pack, but to no avail.

Anyone that can help on this would be great. I am using Visial Studios 2008 v 9.0.

Comment: what type is your font [TrueType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) or [OpenType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType)?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this comment here, yes it was OpenType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, it was the file extension. SSRS 2008 doesn't support OpenType font (.otf), so I just downloaded the same font with a TrueType font (.ttf) file extension and it worked fine.